# Edit contents of new Toplevel window

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to understand the Toplevel widget in Tkinter. I want to create a window with a button which opens a new window with contents in it upon clicking.

I have this, which opens a new windown fine, but I don't know how to edit the contents of that new window.

```
from Tkinter import *

master = Tk()
C = Canvas(master, width=200, height=100)
C.pack()

def Open():
    top = Toplevel()

b = Button(master, text="Open New Window", command=Open)
b.pack()

mainloop()
```

For convenience, let's just say I wanted that new window to contain some text, eg: "Hello World!"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [`Toplevel`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/toplevel.htm) almost exactly as you use the root window:

```
from Tkinter import *

master = Tk()
C = Canvas(master, width=200, height=100)
C.pack()

def Open():
    top = Toplevel()
    # Add a label to the TopLevel, just like you would the root window
    lbl = Label(top, text="Hello World")
    lbl.pack()

b = Button(master, text="Open New Window", command=Open)
b.pack()

mainloop()
```

Demonstration:

[image]

The important thing is to make sure that the widgets you want placed in the `Toplevel` have the correct parent.  In the above code, you'll notice that I gave the label `top` as its parent since I want it to go in the `Toplevel`.

Answer (score 2):

Toplevel is similar to a Frame, you just add widgets inside it using pack or grid. Using your example, I've added a label with it's text tied to a StringVar:

```
from Tkinter import *

master = Tk()
C = Canvas(master, width=200, height=100)
C.pack()

some_string = StringVar(master, "Hello, World!")


def Open():
    top = Toplevel()
    some_frame = Frame(top)
    some_label = Label(some_frame, textvariable=some_string)
    some_label.pack()
    some_frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=TRUE)

b = Button(master, text="Open New Window", command=Open)
b.pack()

mainloop()
```